# Segmentation fault when building a xarray dataset

Tags: python, python-xarray, coredump

I'm trying to build a xarray DataSet with specific coordinates, dimensions, variable names. The values of the variables are left empty for now. Here's my code:

```
dsnew = xr.Dataset(coords={"time": times, "station": stations})
for varname in varnames:
    data = np.empty((ntime, nsta), dtype=np.float32)
    dsnew[varname] = xr.DataArray(data, coords={'time': times,'station': stations}, dims=['time','station'])
```

where `times` and `stations` are two given 1D lists, `ntime` and `nsta` are their lengths. `varnames` is a list of wanted variable names.

But I kept getting error messages like 'Segmentation fault      (core dumped)'. I have a feeling that it is about the memory assigned to this program, but can't tell the exact problem. Does anybody know where I did wrong?

Comment: This looks totally fine to me. Can you edit your question to provide the full example that runs straight through, as a [mre]? And is there any traceback or warnings that are spit out or is it just abruptly terminated with that message?

Comment: When minimizing my code, I found out that the problem causing core dump is the coordinate. I was using a list with arrays, e.g.:

[array('a', dtype=object), array('b', dtype=object), array('c', dtype=object), ...]

When I adjust this to a simple list, e.g.:

['a', 'b', 'c', ...]

then it works